# Algorithm that find cutoff of array

Tags: discrete-signals

I'm looking for an algorithm that can find a significant change in an array, I mean that I know that the data have 3 part of different behavior.

For example:
[image]
For this array I need it to return this two values.
I thought to use the second derivative, but didn't succeed to get a good result.
Any help?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Please clarify what do you mean by array, is it a physical sensor/source array, a programming "construct" of a vector (holding most probably numerical values)? What exactly is that you are looking for? What is this array and what is its "behavior"? There's a lot of information missing here.

Comment: It's a vector of numerical values, that have 3 parts. I'm want to find two points in the vector that divide the values to three parts. By behavior I mean that each of the part have it's own characteristics like ave gradient, concaveness/linearity maybe some other feature as well that can by easily seen.

Comment: Since the gradient and concavity are very discernible, wouldn't you be able to calculate them and from that reach the conclusion of the changing points?

Comment: to make it easier let's let's say it's just about gradient. what is the common algorithm to divide the vector to parts with different gradient.

Comment: The gradient doesn't exactly the same for each part, it is approximately similar for the part.

Comment: From what you've shown, it seems that the middle part has a very small gradient so it shouldn't be that hard to get an estimate with some "simple" finite difference approximation. For example, if you calculate the finite-difference approximation of the gradient for each point you'll see where there is a large change in the gradient and this point will correspond to the "change of parts". As I said, without more information it won't be easy to say more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145034/discussion-between-zaellixa-and-chaospredictor).

Answer (score 2):

I will try to provide an answer to your question but I do think that it will be very specific to your problem and quite the opposite of *generic*.

In the discussion [https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63294347#63294347] you do provide the vector with the gradient at each data point so I will use that to try and provide a possible solution to your problem. For the sake of completeness, below is a graph of the data you provided.

[image: Gradient of data points]

I trust that you have calculated the data in some "meaningful/appropriate" way but since you don't provide much more information I am not able to provide an insight on that.

### Idea

The idea is to try and pinpoint the position that the gradient behavior changes from some "arbitrary" value to something very small, which is a way to identify the plateau region of your data (this has derivative close to $0$).

The derivative provides another indication of the trend of the data. That is, when the derivative is positive, the value of the data increases, while in the opposite case, the value of the data decrease. Thus, if you are sure that the maximum of your data occurs at the plateau, then by the sign of the derivative you'll be able to identify whether you are at a up-slope or down-slope region (but if you are sure that the up-slope occurs first and the down-slope after the plateau, this is redundant).

### Filtering

Since you already have the gradient, you should filter the values to acquire a smoother representation and get rid of noise. I have tried to use two different filters, the moving average and the median.

I tried various values for the filter lengths and decided to go with the value $N = 64$ just from visual inspection of the data.

Below is a graph showing the data and the result of both filtering processes.

[image: Filtered data]

You can see that in both cases, the plateau of your data shows as a horizontal line close to $0$ since the gradient (i.e. the change in your data values) is very small there.

A simple thresholding operation could provide an approximate position for the index where the plateau starts. For demonstration I chose an arbitrary value close to $0$, $t = 2$. The next graph, shows a zoomed-in part of the previous graph around the position of the change to the plateau region (around $n = 280$). Note that in this case I have also included the threshold line in red.

[image: Zoomed gradient and filtered data at the plateau change]

As is evident in the graph, the median filter is better at "pinpointing" the position of the transition between the two regions (as this is depicted by the gradient though). This is a "feature" of the median filter, which preserves the edges of the data. On the contrary, the moving average filter has a slower response and "misses" the point by some index values. This strongly (if not entirely) depends on the filter length.

One more, in my opinion not so important, observation is that the constant value, at the plateau, of the two filters is not the same, and in the case of the moving average filter it is not $0$. The following graph depicts this at some random position of the plateau region.

[image: Zoomed graph at some random part of the plateau region]

The non-zero value of the moving average filter is due to what the filter does exactly, *averaging* where the positive values exhibited by the noisy gradient data moves the average value away from zero. On the contrary, the median filter does not exhibit such behavior because the majority of the data lie on the $x$ axis (are $0$) and the non-zero values will very rarely be in the middle of the sorted values inside the filter vector (this is part of the median filtering process).

As I said, since both values lie well below the threshold value this is not very important, at least compared to the "slow response" of the moving average filter. Whether the "lag" of the moving average filter is important to your application, or going with shorter filter lengths would be fine for you depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve.

### Additional remarks

If you require a more mathematically rigorous treatment of the problem you should definitely struggle for an approach closer to what other contributors have already answered here. Otherwise, I believe that this simplified and rather "naive" (from a formulation point-of-view) approach would be sufficient.

Furthermore, I am wondering whether you could somehow improve the gradient calculation process. I don't have direct access to the original data to check but I am wondering whether the results would look "better" (not entirely sure how to define better in the context of your problem though) if you were to use some higher order finite difference scheme. You could possibly check that too. Since the original data seem quite smooth, I kinda doubt that this would improve the results but I am not an expert on the field to be able to say without testing first.

Answer (score 1):

The method of finding the cutoff frequency consists of two steps

1. Define exactly what you mean by cutoff
2. Implement an algorithm that does exactly what you first line says.

I know, that sounds kind of stupid but it's actually the correct way to approach the problem. The "hard work" is mostly in line #1.

Let's look at the example of a lowpass filter. There isn't one standard way to define it. First, we need to define the cutoff amplitude. This will depend on your application and/or the filter type. For example, for Butterworth filter this is the "half-power" or -3dB point. For an elliptical filter it's typically the passband ripple, etc.

Things are more complicated if the data somewhat noisy (e.g. from a measurement) and passes through the cutoff amplitude multiple times in the cutoff region. For example you can choose

- The highest frequency where the magnitude is higher than the cutoff amplitude
- The lowest frequency where the magnitude is lower than the cutoff amplitude
- The arithmetic of geometric mean of the two.
- The criteria above restricted to a "crossover region" (which is helpful when you are dealing with noisy measurements of equiripple filters).
- etc

All of these are VALID definitions, which one to use depends on the filter, the quality of the data and the requirements of your application. Once you have decided one one, you can just implement it.

For example if you go with the first one, start searching your data from the end and find the first point that's above your chosen cutoff amplitude.

The same methodology can be applied to other filters with appropriate modifications: highpass, bandpass (which is what you have), peaking filters, shelfs, etc.